# Neo4j How to query to all children nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

In the picture, you may see an example of a graph.
If I do the query

```
MATCH (u:UserNode)-[:PROMOTER_OF]->(c:UserNode)
where u.promoterName="Antal"
RETURN u;
```

I only get as result MAIEREAN. But if I expand MAIEREAN, I can see SAMOILA who has MESTER, NICA and SOMOGYI as children and so on...

I would like to know: starting from Antal, how can I write my query in order to show also all children, grandchildre, greatgrandchildren, and so on from the first to the last one?
(FYI: I don't know in advance how long the hierarchy is).

I know something like OPTIONAL MATCH so I tried this

```
Match (u:UserNode)
WHERE u.promoterName="Antal"
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:PROMOTER_OF]->(c:UserNode)
RETURN c;
```

but it will return the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
MATCH (u:UserNode{promoterName:"Antal"})-[:PROMOTER_OF*]->(c:UserNode)
RETURN c;
```

You can add a number together with the asterisk (e.g. PROMOTER_OF* 3) or a range (e.g. PROMOTER_OF* 1..5).
If you have a lot of data I do not recommend using a bare asterisk.